# How do I export only the stock name & live price to a .txt file without any extra lines or unwanted data in between?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am scraping live stock prices from a website using BeautifulSoup and exporting it to a text file using Python. The code returns the price along with additional lines and information.

How can I select only specific information to be exported to a .txt file?

I am not very well versed yet with python. Tried searching stackoverflow but couldn't find anything that worked for me.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time


while True:

    result = requests.get("https://liveindex.org/s&p-futures/")
    src = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    table_body=soup.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

    for row in rows:
        cols=row.find_all('td')
        cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
        print(cols)
        file = open("test.txt", "a")
        file.write(str(cols))
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()

        time.sleep(10) # this will wait for 10 seconds
```

The current code exports data as below:

```
[]

['S&P 500 FUTURES', '2,948.50', '+29.50', '+1.01%', '2,953.62', '2,882.12']

['Open Last Trade : 16:38', 'US Time : Thu Oct 10 2019 16:38']

[]

['S&P 500 FUTURES', '2,948.50', '+29.50', '+1.01%', '2,953.62', '2,882.12']

['Open Last Trade : 16:38', 'US Time : Thu Oct 10 2019 16:38']

[]
```

What I need is (without any blank rows in between):

```
'S&P 500 FUTURES', '2,948.50'

'S&P 500 FUTURES', '2,949.80'
```

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python list tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  Also look for "Python file output tutorial".  StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Learn to access individual list items and how to write to a file; these are skills best learned from existing resources.

Comment: I tried but am not able to format the live flowing data as a proper list/table. Been on it for some days now.

Comment: Then post *your* attempt, rather than the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use, `if` statement to check `cols` is not empty, and `str`'s join to create a comma-separated string from the list `cols` like below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

while True:

    result = requests.get("https://liveindex.org/s&p-futures/")
    src = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    table_body=soup.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')    
    for row in rows:
        cols=row.find_all('td')
        cols = [x.text.strip() for x in cols]
        if cols:
            result = ", ".join(cols)
            print(result)
            with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(result)
                f.write("\n")

        time.sleep(10) # this will wait for 10 seconds
```

Note: I've also used a keyword `with` it basically takes care of the file object's opening and closing automatically.

Read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 0):

`cols` is a list of strings. You need to decide which strings you want to write to the file. For example `cols[0]` will return 'S&P 500 FUTURES'